# Android AlarmManager incomprehensible behavior

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

i know AlarmManager was discussed several times, but i really can't find an answer that can help me. I have an app which needs to start a service at a certain time  and make some stuff, so after some research work, i decided that AlarmManager is what i need.

I use this code to do the job

```
    Intent myIntent=new Intent();
    ComponentName cn=new ComponentName("my.package.name", "my.package.name.AlarmService");
    myIntent.setComponent(cn);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getService(alarm._context, alarm.id, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.time, pendingIntent);
```

Where "alarm" is an object written by me. 
Now, i am sure like the death that this code works, because if i set one (or more) action for 2 minutes or hours forward, it works (i write a log on file in the first instruction of the service). If i execute

```
    adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

I can see all of my pending intents.Ok, happy to see everything working, i schedule my actions  at:

01:00 AM
08:00 AM
08:40 AM
09:15:AM
01:00 PM
02:00 PM
18:00 PM

after setting this actions, i execute

```
   adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

and i can see all of the pending intents. Then i go to sleep and..... when i wake up in the morning at 07:30 AM, the action scheduled at 01:00 AM has not been executed and if i execute

```
    adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

all of my pending intents are disappeared!!!!!!!

I am really frustrated of this behavior, because i spent a lot of time writing this application and i can't get it working properly. I'm posting this question after weeks of researchs, because i tryed every thing, but i still have this problem.  Please help me

Comment: What device/ROM are you on? Have you tried running the app on a different device? I have exactly the same problem on one device (Cyanogenmod 10.1.3, i.e. Android 4.2.2). However, it seems that the problem doesn't occur on a different device (HTC Stock, Android 4.1). Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for `AlarmManager` ([link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)):

> The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing. **This guarantees that the
>   phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast.**
>   Once onReceive() returns, the Alarm Manager releases this wake lock.
>   **This means that the phone will in some cases sleep as soon as your
>   onReceive() method completes.** If your alarm receiver called
>   Context.startService(), it is possible that the phone will sleep
>   before the requested service is launched. **To prevent this, your
>   BroadcastReceiver and Service will need to implement a separate wake
>   lock policy to ensure that the phone continues running until the
>   service becomes available.**

If your `Service` does not also hold set up proper wake locks, the device will go right back to sleep when the `AlarmManager` is finished, you need to manage this as well in your code.

HTH

Comment: Hi Devunwired, first of all thank a lot for answering.
Can you provide me a link to a good example to do this? i'm not a so expert android developer, and there are a lot of things out there about this that get me confused.. thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I would start with the PowerManager docs, since that is how your application code will need to obtain a WakeLock while executing during "sleep": http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: thanks again, i  but as soon as i went in the page i saw written in bold: **Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this API** 

Does it mean that my application will drain the users's battery? is this the only way i can do that? Isn't there a better way to execute some code (**that does not need user interacion**) at a specific time without draining battery?

Comment: That statement is fairly illogical; you cannot wake up a device from sleep to do some work and expect that the battery will not be used to do so.  The reason those statements are there is to keep you aware that you should use those APIs judiciously, and don't keep the device awake longer than you need to do your work.  Holding a WakeLock indefinitely would kill a battery just like leaving the GPS on all the time.

Comment: Ok, you right, it was a stupid statment, but at this point there is something that i do not understain: if i set my pending intent at 2 minutes forward and put the phone to sleep (with the on/off button), and i turn on the phone again after the action should have been executed, i see that the action is executed. But when i set the actions as explained in the main question, the next morning all my pending intents don't exist anymore. What am i missing ?